# Sencha Touch how to load custom CSS , JS if user is using PC or Tablet or SmarthPhone?

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, sencha-touch, navigator

How to setup page so when user is using Pc(Safari/Chrome/Firefox), user gets "normal" web page, but when he is using "ipad" to view the same URL, he gets Sencha Touch(css,js) files to his browser? JavaScript Browser Detection,navigator? Or Sencha has native solution for this? I know about `Ext.env.Browser` but user can have Safari on PC and IPAD? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best and the cleanest solution is to add this functionality on the server side. Check the user-agent request header to decide which files to send. You can also redirect to different sub domain, e.g. to m.example.com. But if you want to do it with sencha then read this article: http://www.sencha.com/learn/idiomatic-layouts-with-sencha-touch

Comment: Thanks, the idea was to check witch "device" is user using and then load different index.html, or to decide witch <script>,<style> to load using javascript, but now that you say its best to deal with it on server side... :-) Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any example of this?

Answer (score 1):

may be you have to use `media query` for this

check this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

http://css-tricks.com/6206-resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: @sandeep- Thanks, but I really need is <script> and <style> custom loading , depending on screen-res, i belive media query is only <style> solution, once web page knows SenchaTouch files need to be loaded then the problem is solved, it uses fullscreen etc... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isiPad  = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;   
    var isiPhone    = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null; 

        if(isiPad){
            alert("Ipad");
            //window.location = "http://www.google.com/iPad/"
        }if(isiPhone){
            alert("Iphone");
            //window.location = "http://www.google.com/iPhone/"
        }else{
            window.location = "http://www.google.com"
        }

</script>
```